# Stop HtmlUnit loading external Javascript/CSS for test performance?

Tags: java, testing, integration-testing, htmlunit

Like many people I use HtmlUnit to do the user testing for my application.  Most of my webpages include google analytics, KISSmetrics etc javascript that I would like to stop HtmlUnit from loading so that the tests don't spend time loading scripts multiple times from the internet.

Is there any way to stop HtmlUnit from loading those scripts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to suppress execution of separae javasript by implementing your own 
[ScriptPreProcessor](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/ScriptPreProcessor.html). I haven't tried it yet, but it seams to be a promising approach.
You could implement your ScriptPreProcessor the way that it detects the jsvascript you do not want to execute and than remove it from the web site.

Comment: From what I can tell, it still loads the remote Javascript - you just have a change to modify or return different content for a remote script using ScriptPreProcessor, but you can't stop HtmlUnit loading it first.  Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
WebClient client=new WebClient();
new FalsifyingWebConnection(client)
{
    @Override
    public WebResponse getResponse(WebRequest settings) throws IOException
    {
        if (settings.getUrl().toExternalForm().startsWith("http://analytics.google.com"))
        {
           return createWebResponse(settings, "", "text/javascript");
        }
        return super.getResponse(settings);
    }
};
```

Comment: Use ```"application/javascript"``` to avoid obsolete media type warning